# Scala class fields not visible

Tags: scala

I have the following class, nested in an object called `Solution`:

```
class TreeNode(l_son: TreeNode, r_son: TreeNode,
               l_val: Int, r_val: Int, nr: Int)
```

Also, in the object `Solution` I try to reference its fields:

```
def query(left: Int, right: Int, node: TreeNode): Int = {
        var sum = 0;
        if(left <= node.l_val && node.r_val <= right) {
            sum = node.nr
        }
```

However, every time I reference one of its fields, I get an error:

> Solution.scala:36: error: value l_val is not a member of Solution.TreeNode
>               if(left <= node.l_val && node.r_val <= right) {
>                               ^
>   Solution.scala:36: error: value r_val is not a member of Solution.TreeNode
>               if(left <= node.l_val && node.r_val <= right) {
>                                             ^
>   Solution.scala:37: error: value nr is not a member of Solution.TreeNode
>                   sum = node.nr

I thought that getters and setters are created automatically for the fields. If that is true, why can't I access them?

Comment: For `case` class yes, not for "normal" class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A declaration like `class TreeNode(l_son: TreeNode, r_son: TreeNode,
               l_val: Int, r_val: Int, nr: Int)`
does not define any class members, just constructor arguments. You can still use them inside the class body almost as if they were members (except, you can't do `this.l_son`), because entire body is defined inside the constructor, so it's essentially a closure.

To define a class member as a constructor parameter, you have to prefix it with `val` or `var` in the constructor parameter list: 
`class TreeNode(val l_son: TreeNode ...)`

Case classes are special in that they will create a (immutable) member for every constructor parameter automatically, along with a bunch of other automatic members that make case classes useful.